# Bash script and created processes

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, sh

I have a bash script running as a su cron every 10 minutes.
On top of the script I declare:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

In crontab I am running it with /bin/bash.
I do the same with all the scripts called from my main script.

I noticed that two threads are created:

```
/bin/bash /main/script
/bin/sh -c /main/script
```

Also all other scripts that are called get their own single thread (only bash).

Could you explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron uses a shell to run the commands. In that user's case that's `/bin/sh`, so for a line like:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /some/script
```

Cron runs:

```
/bin/sh -c '/bin/bash /some/script'
```

If the shell set was `/bin/bash`, it would run:

```
/bin/bash -c '/bin/bash /some/script
```

Now why don't you see the `bash -c` process with bash? Bash, when given a single, simple command, directly `exec`s the command instead of `fork`ing and `exec`ing:

```
$ strace -fe clone,execve bash -c 'bash foo.sh'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "bash foo.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "foo.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
clone(Process 466 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f93bda10a10) = 466
[pid   466] execve("/bin/true", ["/bin/true"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
[pid   466] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=466, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

With `dash`, which is `/bin/sh`:

```
$ strace -fe clone,execve dash -c 'bash foo.sh'
execve("/bin/dash", ["dash", "-c", "bash foo.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
clone(Process 473 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7f31650a10) = 473
[pid   473] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "foo.sh"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
[pid   473] clone(Process 474 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f408d740a10) = 474
[pid   474] execve("/bin/true", ["/bin/true"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
[pid   474] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid   473] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=474, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid   473] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=473, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can see the extra clone here.